# jQuery Multiple Conditionals Help

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements

I'm trying to make an event listener for when a button is 'active' (has an .active class in my case) and a link is clicked, an event happens. But I'm having trouble chaining the two conditionals together and it doesn't seem to work.

```
    if($('.talk').hasClass('active') && $('.goblin').click()){
        alert("the world has gone mad!");
    } else {
        //nothing happens
    }
```

The code is above. Again, the two conditions are:

*The 'Talk' button is active

*The link with class 'Goblin' is clicked

I'm thinking I'll have to use .live() or something for this, but I'm not sure. Help!

Comment: Don't forget to click on the check mark next to my answer to mark it as correct!

Answer (score 3):

You should bind to the click event of Goblin, then check for your active condition:

```
$('.goblin').click(function () {
    if($('.talk').hasClass('active'))
    {
        alert("the world has gone mad!");
    }
});
```